# How to Update properties of a OneDrive item using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update the properties of a OneDrive item using SharePoint REST API.

OneDrive item web URL:

```
https://vx13-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alexw_vx13_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/SrcDir/File-To-Update.txt
```

Mainly looking to updating following fields: Author, Created_x0020_By, Editor, Modified_x0020_By, Modified, Created

I tried using Graph API:

```
Request:
Method: PATCH |
URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/vx13-my.sharepoint.com,eab581b1-a945-4d23-9c8e-ec67bb74a42d,32fa1468-54b6-40d6-abbd-f775c4c3932b/drives/b!sYG16kWpI02cjuxnu3SkLWgU-jK2VNZAq733dcTDkyvIAAMdpSy_Sryiw8ARQ8Gv/root:/SrcDir/File-To-Update.txt:/listItem/fields |
Header:
Content-Type: application/json |
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose |
Body:
{
  "Created": "2019-02-01 10:25 AM",
  "Modified": "2020-01-27 11:25 AM",
  "Modified_x0020_By": "3",
  "Created_x0020_By": "3",
  "Author": "Alex Wilber",
  "Editor": "Alex Wilber"
}
```

It is giving failure response as:

> {"code": "accessDenied", "message": "Field 'Created' is read-only"}

Through CSOM API using `ValidateUpdateListItem()` its working & successfully updating the property fields of OneDrive items.

But is there any way to update property fields of OneDrive item through REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint REST API,
a work around to update the Properties of OneDrive item using method ValidateUpdateListItem()

Get the list-item-id of the file

```
GET https://vx13-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alexw_vx13_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/personal/alexw_vx13_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/SrcDir/File-To-Update.txt')/listitemallfields/fieldvaluesastext?$select=Id
```

Update Author, Editor, Created & Modified fields of list item using ValidateUpdateListItem

```
POST https://vx13-my.sharepoint.com/personal/alexw_vx13_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items(<list-item-id>)/ValidateUpdateListItem()

Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose

Body:
{
    "formValues":
    [
        {
            "FieldName": "Created",
            "FieldValue": "2019/02/01 10:25 AM"
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "Modified",
            "FieldValue": "2020/01/27 11:25 AM"
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "Author",
            "FieldValue": "[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|test_user_AK@vx13.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "Editor",
            "FieldValue": "[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|test_user_JV@vx13.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
        }
    ],
    "bNewDocumentUpdate": true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) under the **Properties** section, you will notice certain fields are **read only** and you wont be able to update them using Graph API.

For all other properties(e.g. name), follow this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to update.

Being said that, you can always request for a feature by filling a [User Voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that it goes into our backlog.

Answer (score 0):

By default, these properties are Readonly by and cannot be edited.

You need to set the ReadOnlyField to false to update these fields. I used to answer the same question here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/221106/rest-api-to-create-item-with-custom-created-by-and.html

For Created By column:

```
Url: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Mylist')/fields/getbytitle('Created By')

 Body:
     {
     "__metadata": { "type": "SP.FieldUser"},
     "ReadOnlyField": false
     }
```

For Created column:

```
Url: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Mylist')/fields/getbytitle('Created')
 Body:
     {
     "__metadata": { "type": "SP.FieldDateTime"},
     "ReadOnlyField": false
     }
```